# Format input date set

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Hello I have problems when displaying and giving a suitable format to my input date, when loading the page it receives through props values ​​which I receive and in the useEffect I pass them like this:

```
   useEffect(() => {
         setUsuario(props.history.location.state);
    }, [])
```

my setUsuario is:

```
const [usuario,setUsuario]= useState({
    usuEcode        : '',         
    usuName         : '',         
    usuDni          : '',         
    usuAddress      : '',         
    usuEmail        : '',         
    usuPassword     : '',         
    usuPhone        : '',         
    usuCelhphone    : '',         
    usuBirthday     : '',         
    usuId           : '',         
    usuIni          : '',         
    usuFin          : '',         
    usuUniversity   : '',         
    usuDegree       : '',         
    devId           : '',         
    recId           : '',            
    usuBasicAmount  : '',          
    payId           : '',            
    usuCuentabanco  : ''             
});
```

then I try to show it in input date like this

```
<Input type="date" name="usuBirthday" value={usuario.usuBirthday} onChange={ingresarValoresMemoria} id="date" placeholder="" />
```

but he doesn't show me
when printing in the console it shows me the values ​​in this way

```
2021-10-11T00:00:00
```

How can I give it the format that my input date expects and show it in this format "DD/MM/YYYY"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) library

```
// date should be 2021-10-11T00:00:00
const value = moment(usuario.usuBirthday).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
// value ==>  11/10/2021 
<Input ... value={value} ... />
```

Comment: console.log('Date',moment(props.history.location.state.usuBirthday).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));                        I pass it like this and it shows me but I don't know how to pass the formatted value to my input.

Comment: Remove last's `)` bracket then try as I have updated answer

Comment: How do I pass it to my input date?

Comment: I do that in the useEffect because when rendering the page it should show it

Comment: Yes it should be

Comment: and how do I update the value to my entity and then send it to my api

Comment: Not getting you exactly what you want. Code should work if `usuario.usuBirthday` value is `2021-10-11T00:00:00`